# How to determine if a json field exists within an array in presto?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, presto, redash

If I have a field `jsonCol` which has list of json objects, for example:

```
[{'name': 'fieldA', 'enum': 'someValA'},
 {'name': 'fieldB', 'enum': 'someValB'},
 {'name': 'fieldC', 'enum': 'someValC'}]
```

Another row may look like:

```
[{'name': 'fieldA', 'enum': 'someValA'},
 {'name': 'fieldC', 'enum': 'someValC'}]
```

How do I get rows where the `fieldB` exists?
I have a query that can look for the value of `fieldB`, howver the query fails in cases when `fieldB` doesn't exist with the error:

```
Error running query: Array subscript must be less than or equal to array length: 1 > 0
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(filter(cast(json_parse(jsonCol) AS array(json)), x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.name') = 'fieldB')[1], '$.enum') AS myField
FROM myTable
WHERE
    json_extract_scalar(filter(cast(json_parse(jsonCol) AS array(json)), x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.name') = 'fieldB')[1], '$.enum') = 'someValB'
```

How can I check for the value of `someValB` but also ignore cases when the json doesn't exist at all?

Comment: @forpas Sorry, running this on Redash which uses presto query engine. I updated the title and tags.

Comment: Note that you can just change your select to `select 'someValB' myField ...` since you are filtering based on the same selected value being equal to `someValB`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`element_at`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#element_at) instead of array access with `[1]`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (jsonCol) as (
    values ('[{"name": "fieldA", "enum": "someValA"},
 {"name": "fieldB", "enum": "someValB"},
 {"name": "fieldC", "enum": "someValC"}]'),
        ('[{"name": "fieldA", "enum": "someValA"},
 {"name": "fieldC", "enum": "someValC"}]')
)

-- query
SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(
        element_at(
            filter(cast(json_parse(jsonCol) AS array(json)), x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.name') = 'fieldB'),
            1)
        , '$.enum') AS myField
FROM dataset
WHERE
    json_extract_scalar(
        element_at(
            filter(cast(json_parse(jsonCol) AS array(json)), x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.name') = 'fieldB'),
            1)
        , '$.enum') = 'someValB';
```

Output:

```
 myField
----------
 someValB
```

Note that possibly you can simplify the query by moving some parts into `WITH` clause or subquery.

If you can switch to Trino - you can use it's improved json path support via [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-query) (or `json_exists`). TBH I don't fully understand your goal but here are some options:

```sql
-- query
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(jsonCol, 'lax $[*]?(@.name == "fieldB" && @.enum == "someValB")[0].enum') myField,
    JSON_QUERY(jsonCol, 'lax $[*]?(@.name == "fieldB").enum' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER) myFieldArr
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
  myField   |  myFieldArr
------------+--------------
 "someValB" | ["someValB"]
 NULL       | NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution for `SQLite`.

`json_each()` used to returns row for each array element or object member.

`json_extract()` extracts and returns one or more values from json object.

```
with cte as (
  select key, value, json_extract(value,'$.name') as name, json_extract(value,'$.enum') as enum
  from myTable, json_each(jsonCol)
)
select enum
from cte
where name = 'fieldB';
```

Result :

```
enum
———————-
someValB
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UGHoM-HE)

Comment: How would you return the entire row that contains an array with fieldB with value  someValB? I expect the output to be the first row of myTable. With your example, I don't know how to connect the subquery results to the table.

Comment: Is this what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/vGJJwYJe

Comment: There is no `json_each` function in Presto/Trino.

Comment: I didn’t realize that the question tags have been changed from SQLite to Presto !